# How is $\delta \theta$ related to angular resolution?

Tags: terminology

Does the expression $\delta \theta \sim 3 ^\circ $ have a special meaning other than *about 3 degrees*?

I was searching for the angular resolution of neutrino detectors and looking at the Super-Kamiokande article, [there it says](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Super-Kamiokande&oldid=933421203#Realtime_supernova_monitor):

> The angular resolution, therefore, can be as good as $\delta \theta \sim 3 ^\circ $ for a supernova at the center of our Galaxy.

I thought $\theta$ was supposed to be theta, an angle designator and $\delta$ should designate a difference, though it seems to be not sensible to talk about a difference here. While the Wikipedia article on [angular resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_resolution) in fact uses $\theta$ for angular resolution, it does not use delta.

Is there a special meaning to this or can I treat this as angle of 3 degree?

Comment: The maximum difference between two angles I can't distinguish between them (with my apparatus) is $\delta \theta$. It is about 3 degrees (according to what you're citing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbol $\delta$ is often used to represent an error bar. I would assume that it means that the "error circle" of any detection has a radius of about 3 degrees projected onto the sky. This error bar will be a function of the angular resolution but not necessarily equal to it.

There is ambiguity, angular resolution would often be quoted as the FWHM ([full width at half maximum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_width_at_half_maximum)) of the point spread function, but a wide FWHM does not necessarily mean that you can't locate something more accurately than that.

In fact $\delta \theta \sim $FWHM/SNR, where SNR is the signal-to-noise ratio of your detection. Indeed, the reference that your question points to suggests that is exactly what is going on here. It suggests $\delta \theta \sim 30^{\circ}/\sqrt{N}$, where $N$ is the detected number of neutrinos. But the Poissonian SNR of such a detection *is* $\sqrt{N}$, so I deduce that the angular FWHM of the detector response to a single neutrino (which is what I would refer to as the angular resolution, since if 2 supernovae went off at the same time only 15 degree apart, you wouldn't be able to distinguish their separate locations) is 30 degrees, and the 3 degree figure comes about because you might detect 100 neutrinos from a supernova at the centre of the Galaxy.